# Exceção com variáveis

Tags: c++, exceção

Sou meio novo com tratamento de exceções, o que eu queria fazer era ler uma variável em c++ e caso ela ser diferente do tipo da qual eu declarei cair no catch.

```
int x;
try {
    cin >> x;
} catch (...) {
    cout << "Tipo errado" << endl;
}
```

Na qual a entrada poderia ser qualquer coisa, desde cadeia de caracteres e tal.

Comment: E por que faria isto? Programadores C++ não fazem isto? Existe alguma razão para querer usar filosofia de outra linguagem aqui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está usando cin, você deve verificar seu failbit, pode fazer isso de duas formas:

```
if (!cin) {
     trow "Tipo errado";
}
```

OU

```
cin >> x;

while (!cin.good())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n')
    cin >> x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você faria assim:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 0;

    try {
        cin >> x;
        if (x == 0) throw "Tipo errado";
    } catch(char const* msg) {
        cout << msg << endl;
    }
}
```